# Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'Object' in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have some object:

```
const obj = { age: 25, name: "Michal", gender: "Male" }
type Object = typeof obj
```

Then, I have type helper, that will return type of the specified property from this object:

```
type Value<Key extends keyof Object> = Object[Key]

Value<"age"> // number
```

What I should do, if `Key` in `Value` could be also void? Something like this:

```
type Value<Key extends void | keyof Object> = Key extends void ? never : Object[Key]
```

But it doesn't work and error appears:

> Type 'Key' cannot be used to index type 'Object'

How can I fix it?

Comment: why do you want to use `void` here?

Comment: `Key extends keyof Object` already precludes the possibility of it being anything other than a key from the object, so checking for anything else is redundant. As already mentioned `void` is not an appropriate type to use here anyway, it signifies a valueless function return.

Comment: "What I should do, if `Key` in `Value` could be also void?" It could not be `void`, it can only be the the properties that you defined in `obj`. If you have an example where it could be void, you should show it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently a design limitation or missing feature of TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#48710](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48710) and  [microsoft/TypeScript#26240](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26240) (and probably others) for relevant issues.

[Conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) of the form `T extends U ? TrueBranch<T> : FalseBranch<T>` can narrow the type `T` to the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#conditional-type-constraints) `U` in the *true* branch, becoming something like `TrueBranch<T & U>`.  But there is no narrowing whatsoever in the *false* branch.  TypeScript doesn't have *negated types* of the form `not U` (this was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#29317](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317)  but was never released), so there's no way to express `FalseBranch<T & not U>` in the general case.

(And in the general case it's not even true; consider that `(0 | "") extends (number | string) is true, but` (0 | "") extends number`is false... but this does not imply that`(0 | "") extends string`.)

You just get `FalseBranch<T>` for the original, un-narrowed `T`.  In specific cases where both `T` and `U` are [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types), then you could filter `T` to something like [`Exclude<T, U>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion), but this has not yet been implemented.

---

Luckily, there are workarounds.  In cases like yours, you only really need `Key` to be narrowed to `keyof Object`; you don't care about narrowing to `void`, because you produce `never` if `Key` is `void`.  You can simply reverse the sense of the check so that the true branch and the false branch are in different places:

```
type Value<Key extends void | keyof Object> = 
  Key extends keyof Object ? Object[Key] : never; // okay
```

---

Of course, in some situations, you really need to narrow both in the true branch and in the false branch, so you can't simply swap what you're checking:

```
type Foo = { x: string, y: number };
type Bar = { a: string, b: number };

type BazBad1<K extends keyof Foo | keyof Bar> =
  K extends keyof Foo ? Foo[K] : Bar[K]; // error!

type BazBad2<K extends keyof Foo | keyof Bar> =
  K extends keyof Bar ? Bar[K] : Foo[K]; // error!
```

In these cases you can add a redundant check to get the desired behavior:

```
type Baz<K extends keyof Foo | keyof Bar> =
  K extends keyof Foo ? Foo[K] : 
  K extends keyof Bar ? Bar[K] : 
  never; // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJKiSwLIDyARgFYTwAuAygBYCWEGAJnkURIl4Ae2BQmSEfSQBePEhABzCAC4kAJgCsAGlLg1SAEQBZDvDaYjelcB4QATutOYIRpAF9BQpgE8Y1PSMkvJ+ASIAZlL03iRhyABqmACuEAA8ANIQvkgQAB5MEHZQSABuIhx8AD5IANbZkUi0DMwAfHKxQlk5+YXFdQ1RzcFIAPxNQcwA2t0AukjqwBCljgDcSAD0G1K1IL4CxD7+yABiIiJyCnnqEg4cwEp6vovJYDSOnqud8UgAQiAOS64RQ3Jh3B56GgvN4fDxfQjfY5-EBYf48ACMmVyBSKPBK9V8jTOFxqBMa-wc7VknRIGWxfTxA0JUWJYyQxJm83UFM56y2uQcDhEDgAhAchEgfv9USAeBosb1cfjBuzzkhSSqKVSaUg6Yr+mSohS2TyMlzVSJeZtto4haKDoiAsisAqcQaVayNczkZSOocJXq3YzDRa2RyzQtdfSlUzyQCTQDOZGlisHHztiJdvtDl5CB4gA)